# Error propagation question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, data-analysis

Lets say I have built a rotating device. Now I want to measure how
accurate the rotation is. For this I use a measuring instrument with a
resolution of $0.1^\circ$  with an uncertainty of $\pm0.2^\circ$ . I
first rotate the device to a starting point ($-20^\circ$) and measure the
actual value (val_start). I now let the device rotate, lets say about
$35.0^\circ$  to $+15^\circ$ and take a measurement after the rotation (val_end) with
my instrument. I repeat this N times. Now I want to estimate the
how accurate my device is and how strong it deviates. Here is some
exemplary data (N=4):

| ID | val_start / degree | abs_start_error / degree | val_end / degree | abs_end_error / degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -20.8 | -0.8 | 14.7 | -0.3 |
| 2 | -19.3 | 0.7 | 15.1 | 0.1 |
| 3 | -20.1 | -0.1 | 15.3 | 0.3 |
| 4 | -18.9 | 1.1 | 14.9 | -0.1 |

From both absolute errors I can calculate a standard deviation:

$$ \sigma_{start} = \frac{1}{4}\sum x_i^2 = 0.5875^\circ $$
$$ \sigma_{end} = \frac{1}{4}\sum y_i^2 = 0.05^\circ $$

As you can see, $\sigma_{end}$ is smaller than the uncertainty of the measuring device. And now to my questions:

1. How to proceed correctly? Is the total uncertainty just $\sigma_{start}^{tot} = \sqrt{0.2^2 + 0.5875^2}$ ?
2. Am I even allowed to use that many decimals?

Comment: what are $x_i$ and $y_i$?

Comment: corresponding abs_start_error and abs_end_error

Comment: Note that $ +15^{\circ} - (-20^{\circ}) = 35^{\circ} \ne 45^{\circ}$

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing because your errors aren't errors. I mean they are, but the language is confusing. One error is a bias, and another error is an uncertainty.

The first error ("abs_start_error") is not a measurement uncertainty, it is in fact a measurement of your instrument's bias. As stated in the problem, the uncertainty of those measurements is $\sigma = 0.2^{\circ}$.

Skipping the error analysis of the start/stop accuracy, we can go straight to the 35 degree rotation, defining the angle $a$ to be "val_end - val_start":

$$ a_i = [35.5^{\circ}, 34.4^{\circ}, 35.4^{\circ}, 33.8^{\circ}]$$

Those have a mean value:

$$ \bar a = 34.8^{\circ} $$

Each end point has a $\sigma = 0.2^{\circ}$ uncertainty, so any rotation measurement has an uncertainty:

$$ \sigma_R = \sqrt{\sigma_{start}^2 + \sigma_{end}^2} = \sqrt 2 \sigma = 0.3^{\circ} $$

Meanwhile, the standard deviation of the $N$ measurements: $a_i$ is:

$$ \sigma_a = 0.71^{\circ}$$

You can assume the rotation angle variance is the sum of your instrument's variance and the measurement variance, that is:

$$ \sigma^2_a = \sigma^2_I + \sigma^2_R $$

so that:

$$ \sigma_I = \sqrt{\sigma_a^2 - \sigma_R^2} = 0.65^{\circ} $$

So that is the precision of your rotation. You asked for accuracy. That is determined by the deviation of $\bar a$ from 35 degrees:

$$ \delta_a = 35^{\circ} - \bar a = -0.22^{\circ} $$

The uncertainty of that measurement is the standard error of the mean:

$$ \sigma_{\bar a} = \frac{\sigma_a}{\sqrt{N}} = 0.50^{\circ} $$

That is, the accuracy is:

$$ \delta_a = -0.22^{\circ} \pm 0.50^{\circ} $$

For completeness, you can also get an uncertainty on the precision using the standard error on the variance:

$$ \sigma_{VAR} =  (N-1)[(N-1)\mu_4 - (N-3)\mu_2^2]/N^3\frac{N}{N-1} $$

where the $\mu_n$ are the $n^{\rm th}$ central moments of the distribution. That gives:

$$ \sigma_I = 0.65^{\circ} \pm 0.15^{\circ} $$